# What 'objective' means in following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> "Dhrisrashtra is the very image of ignorance; and Sanjaya is the embodiment of self-restraint. **Ignorance lurks at the core of the [*objective*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objective), the outward-looking", mind**. With his mind enveloped in darkness, Dhrisrashtra is blind since birth, but he sees and hears through Sanjay, the epitome of self-control."

I checked the Merriam Webster dictionary, but I can't figure out which definition of objective best fits here.

Does objective in this context means: **Unbiased**?

Answer (score 1):

The words "the outward-looking" seem to have been written specifically to help the reader understand what the writer means by "objective" here. In this case I believe the relevant [Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objective) is:

> **objective**, *adjective*
>   ...
>   1 d : involving or deriving from sense perception or experience with actual objects, conditions, or phenomena * objective awareness * objective data
>   ...

Answer (score 1):

Without a larger piece of context, any explanation is tentative. So.

Tentatively then, the author divides minds (outlooks, philosophies) as objective and subjective. The objective mind looks to the outer world of physical facts, while the subjective mind looks inward and interprets the world around him or her in terms of feelings.

So, no, unbiased doesn't fit here.

Comment: Thank you! I am reading a book (hard copy). If you want I can write an entire paragraph. Please let me know.